# Trying to understand closure with a sum of functions applied to object

Tags: ruby, closures

I have three functions (they work), that I think could be done using closure. Here is what I do :

```
def sum_with_first_function (parent)
  total=0
  parent.items.each do |item|
    total+= BuisnessLogic.new(item).first_function
  end
  total
end

def sum_with_second_function (parent)
  total=0
  parent.items.each do |item|
    total+= BuisnessLogic.new(item).second_function
  end
  total
end

def sum_with_third_function
 .....
```

As you can see all it do is the sum of the items with first, second or third function.

Is it possible to modify this code to use closure and give the function to use as an argument?

Answer (score 4):

You could just pass the method name as a symbol, then use `.send` method to call it.

```
def sum_with(parent, method)
  parent.items.inject(0){ |sum, item| sum + BuisnessLogic.new(item).send method }
end

# usage
sum_with(parent, :first_method)
sum_with(parent, :second_method)
```